# Why set in python choose first element from list of string with different character encoding?

Tags: python, unicode, set, python-unicode

Why **set()** in Python add to set first element with different character encoding (ASCII, Unicode)? 
For example

```
list1, list2 = [u'string' , 'string'], ['string', u'string']
set1, set2 = set(list1), set(list2)
```

And when I print set1 and set2 they have different outputs

```
print(set1)
(set([u'string'])

print(set2)
(set(['string']))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unicode and regular strings with the same *ASCII* contents get the same hash and are considered equal:

```
>>> hash(u'string')
-9167918882415130555
>>> hash('string')
-9167918882415130555
>>> u'string' == 'string'
True
```

Putting two 'equal' objects into a set results in just one object remaining. It then only matters in *what order* you put in your strings.

In CPython, the first object wins; in your samples, one puts `u'string'` first, so adding `'string'` to the same set has no effect, and in the other sample `'string'` is first so adding `u'string'` has no effect.

This only applies of both the `str` object can be decoded as ASCII. Any data beyond that codepoint and the above no longer holds true; you even get a specific warning when you try to test for equality anyway:

```
>>> 'stringå' == u'stringå'
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
>>> 'stringå' in set([u'stringå'])
False
>>> set([u'stringå', 'stringå'])
set([u'string\xe5', 'string\xc3\xa5'])
```

My terminal happens to be set to UTF-8, so entering `å` into an interactive session really ends up as the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence C3 A5; this is not decodable as ASCII, so comparisons fail and the `str` and `unicode` version no longer test as equal and show up as separate objects in a `set`. The Python interpreter auto-decoded `u'stringå'` from UTF-8 to form the `unicode` object.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the order: [**u'string'** , 'string'], ['string', **u'string'**]

In your case it just returns first unique value **u'string'** and **'string'** respectively.

```
In [7]: list1, list2 = [u'string' , 'string'], [u'string', 'string']

In [8]: set1, set2 = set(list1), set(list1)

In [9]: set1
Out[9]: {u'string'}

In [10]: set2
Out[10]: {u'string'}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all a [set object](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/661cdbd617b8/Objects/setobject.c) preserve the unique elements , and when you use `set` function on a list it get's the items from the list at the first index and then checks if there was any element with same *hash value* then it doesn't insert that element in set.

Also you may note that unicodes and ASCII strings have same hash value!